# HTML5 - play a video from web url but for security reason do not allow to download or copy the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have a BANK video file, and the file is confidential so they only give the link to a customer who can open it in Google chrome browser just to watch the video.

But that customer can only view it 
(cant easily download it, or copy the main video link)
How to do that?

i tried  but its very easy for anyone to copy the video URL how do you hide those and lock those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. There are currently no DRM features for HTML 5 video (not that DRM features are all that effective anywhere that has implemented them).

Comment: Can we not temporary use VLC, Mplayer, FFMPeg at-least to just make temporary work? Cause its very strange it cnat be done? is there no way with VLC to do a temporary streaming of that local file from that PC to Google Chrome browser atleast?

Comment: How can we stream VLC that file to a temporary web link which playes in the Google Chrome?

Comment: There would be nothing stopping the user from saving the video when it gets to their browser.

Comment: NO - if we stream the video file at-least it cant be a downloadable file for the user end it will be only like playing a temporary link.

Comment: I have done another way to achieve this. And its working i will post it as answer but someone should help me to improve it.

Comment: Streaming video doesn't stop users from saving it. It just makes it slightly harder.

Comment: see my answer please, its working and only that user can watch read only.